# How to get elements with attributes using C# XML serializer

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I want to achieve XML in this style using C# XMLseralizer

```
<state id="s1">val<state />
```

But I got this

```
<state id="s1">
  <val>1<val />
<state />
```

with the following code

```
 [XmlType("state")]    
 public class mystate
{
  [XmlAttribute("id")]
  public string id;
  public int val;
}
```

Anyone has hints? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `XmlText` attribute to the member you want as the element content, like so:

```
[XmlType("state")]
public class mystate
{
   [XmlAttribute("id")]
   public string id;

   [XmlText]
   public int val;
}
```